# (not= (type `(1)) (type `(1 2))) ;; Why? (single element list, syntax-quote, Cons, PersistentList)

Tags: clojure

I see this behavior in Clojure 1.2.1:

```
user=> (type '(1 2))
clojure.lang.PersistentList
user=> (type `(1 2)) ;; notice syntax-quote
clojure.lang.Cons
user=> (type '(1))
clojure.lang.PersistentList
user=> (type `(1))
clojure.lang.PersistentList
```

I expected `(1) to be a Cons just like `(1 2) is.

I also tried:

```
user=> (type (cons 1 nil)) 
clojure.lang.PersistentList
user=> (type (cons 1 `()))
clojure.lang.Cons
user=> (type (cons 1 '()))
clojure.lang.Cons
user=> (type (cons 1 []))
clojure.lang.Cons
```

So what is the reason for `(1) and (cons 1 nil) to be PersistentLists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like amalloy says, you shouldn't program against those exact types but against the `seq` abstraction.

However, I think I can take a guess at the reason. The Clojure forms that produce a `PersistentList` ultimately call [RT.java](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/1.2.x/src/jvm/clojure/lang/RT.java#L527), specifically the `cons(Object x, Object coll)` method. It begins with a pretty odd check: `if(coll == null) return new PersistentList(x)`, after which it creates a `Cons` object if that check doesn't pass. If you look at [earlier versions of the code](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/397f768ca30a4615c753ec544dedc5c39be7743b/src/jvm/clojure/lang/RT.java#L202), you can find this:

```
static public IPersistentCollection cons(Object x, IPersistentCollection y) {
    if(y == null)
        return new PersistentList(x);
    return y.cons(x);
}
```

So in an earlier version of the function, the call was dispatched to the `cons` method of the second argument, so the case when the second argument was `null` (i.e. `nil` in Clojure) needed special handling. Later versions don't do that dispatching (or actually do it but in a different way, presumably to support a larger variety of collection types), but the check has been retained since it does not break any correctly written code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That explains the behavior. I thought there's a good reason for things to work this way, but if I understand correctly this is just a quirk, right?

Comment: I think so. If you really want to find out, try removing that check and see if anything breaks.

Answer (score 4):

If you care about the difference, your program is incorrect. They're both seqs, in the sense that `(seq? x)` returns true; the rest is implementation details you shouldn't depend on.

Comment: I don't need it for any program :) I just hope to learn something about Clojure.